# Memorizar "não mostrar novamente" com localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Eu tenho uma `div` que pode ser oculta ao clicar em um botão:

```js
$(".fechar").click(function(){
    $("#mensagem").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mensagem">
  <p>(...)</p>
  <button class="fechar">Fechar e não mostrar novamente</button>
</div>
```

O que preciso é que ela não volte mais a aparecer após ser oculta pela primeira vez.

Encontrei uma forma com o *Jquery dialog*, mas ele não me permite personalizar direito, pelo menos não de forma simples, então preciso e prefiro que seja assim.

Como faço para memorizar esta ação no localStorage?

Comment: Mas este código que colocou já faz  exatamente isto.

Comment: Não, @LeAndrade... eu preciso que seja memorizado no localStorage para que, mesmo atualizando a página, esta div não apareça novamente...

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra, veja minha resposta sobre

Comment: Nossa verdade, não prestei atenção!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples, primeiro você precisa capturar no seu evento `click` que a `div` foi clicada, poderia ser algo como:

```
$(".fechar").click(function(){
    $("#mensagem").hide();
    //definindo que foi clicado
    window.localStorage.setItem('clicado', 'clicado');
});
```

E no seu `document.ready()`, verifique se `clicado` está definido, caso estiver, oculte a `div`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   if(window.localStorage.getItem('clicado')) {
        $("#mensagem").hide(); 
   } 
});
```

Seu código final:

```
$(".fechar").click(function(){
    $("#mensagem").hide();
    window.localStorage.setItem('clicado', 'clicado');
});

$(document).ready(function(){ 
   if(window.localStorage.getItem('clicado')) {
        $("#mensagem").hide(); 
        console.log('clicado definido')
   } 
});
```

Veja funcionando no Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x43n7fsu/2/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, amigo! Mas eu fiquei meio perdido... colei esse teu código lá e a função não funcionou. Deve ser porque não estou sabendo usar. Será que você pode por pra mim aqui nesse Fiddle? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hc51vb9d/)

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra  Editei a resposta, olhe agora.

Comment: Perfeito! muito agradecido!!

Comment: Por nada, amigo :D